# Build isolation - Docker container based builds in Bamboo 6.4.0

Tags: docker, bamboo

Finally, it is possible in Bamboo to let a build run in a Docker container without dealing with agent configuration.

The system just asks for a image.

Now, what about the underlying infrastructure, what happens there? 
Will then Bamboo server host just spawn containers locally (which limits horizontal scalability)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Bamboo will spawn the build containers on the agent that the build is running on (either Local, Remote, or, Elastic - depending on your configuration).

In order for this to work the agent will require Docker to be installed and running.

Comment: Wait but whats the difference to docker capability and using docker run in script tasks?

Comment: The difference is that the stated purpose of the Docker runner is to isolate and maximise reproducibility of builds. The Docker tasks are there to interact with the Docker engine (building/running/pushing images).

You are correct that you can achieve a similar outcome by issuing `docker run` commands inside a script task. The Docker runner will automatically mount your working directory.